# How we can draw two series of data in "openpyxl" package of python (line-chart)

Tags: python, openpyxl

Suppose that we have this code:

```
  from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for row in range(1,10):
            value = ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value = row+5

    for row in range(1,10):
            value2 = ws.cell(row=row,column=2).value = row

    wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
    from openpyxl.charts import Reference, Series,LineChart

    values = Reference(ws, (1, 1), (9, 1))
    series = Series(values, title="First series of values")
    chart = LineChart()
    chart.append(series)
    chart.drawing.name = 'This is my chart'
    ws.add_chart(chart)
    wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
```

How can i plot second column values to same line-chart? (and add `legend`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rearranged your code, slightly, so that the chart and its properties are declared before the series are created.  Then, it's simply a matter of repeating your series creation on the second range of values.  As far as I know, unless I'm misunderstanding the question, Excel creates the legend automatically.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in range(1,10):
        value = ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value = row+5

for row in range(1,10):
        value2 = ws.cell(row=row,column=2).value = row

wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")

from openpyxl.charts import Reference, Series,LineChart

# setup the chart
chart = LineChart()
chart.drawing.name = 'This is my chart'

# setup and append the first series
values = Reference(ws, (1, 1), (9, 1))
series = Series(values, title="First series of values")
chart.append(series)

# setup and append the second series
values = Reference(ws, (1, 2), (9, 2))
series = Series(values, title="Second series of values")
chart.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart)
wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
```